# Error VB NET - Juego sencillo con disparos

Tags: vb.net

Hola alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar el problema :
Cuando disparo pasando 2 segundos no pasa nada..pero cuando disparo rapido varias balas se paralizan y reaccionan despues :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando disparo varios misiles se paran o cuelgan solo los misiles,este es el codigo que hace mostrar a los misiles :

```
 Public Sub DispararNave(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
    Dim Bala As New PictureBox

    Me.Controls.Add(Bala)
    Bala.Width = 30
    Bala.Height = 10
    Bala.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    Bala.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Bala.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.NAVE_MALA
    Bala.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    Bala.Top = Y
    Bala.Left = X
    Bala.BringToFront()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 100
        Application.DoEvents()
        Bala.Location = New Point(Bala.Location.X, Bala.Location.Y - 20)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Next


End Sub
```

Si alguien podria ayudarme a encontrar la solucion a este problema por favor :)

Comment: Igualmente se me siguen quedando cuando disparo muy seguido ..!

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo plantearía de diferente forma: que el método disparar simplemente cree la bala y haya un timer que ejecute un método que se encargue de cambiar la posición de todos los elementos de la pantalla y redibujarla.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
Dim ReadOnly _bullets As New List(Of PictureBox)
Dim ReadOnly _screenUpdater As New Timer()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _screenUpdater.Interval = 20
    AddHandler _screenUpdater.Tick, AddressOf UpdateScreen
    _screenUpdater.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateScreen(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If _bullets.Count = 0 Then Return

    For i As Integer = _bullets.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim bullet = _bullets(i)
        If bullet.Location.Y < 20 Then
            Controls.Remove(bullet)
            _bullets.RemoveAt(i)
            bullet.Dispose()
        Else 
            bullet.Location = new Point(bullet.Location.X, bullet.Location.Y - 10)
        End If
    Next
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub

Public Sub DispararNave(x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim bala As New PictureBox
    bala.Width = 30
    bala.Height = 10
    bala.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    bala.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    bala.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.NAVE_MALA
    bala.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    bala.Top = Y
    bala.Left = X
    Controls.Add(bala)
    bala.BringToFront()
    _bullets.Add(bala)
End Sub
```

En la lista _bullets tengo todas las balas que actualmente están activas.

El timer _screenUpdater se encarga de disparar el método UpdateScreen que se encarga de actualizar la pantalla.

El método DispararNave simplemente crea el nuevo PictureBox para la bala en su posición inicial y lo añade a la colección _bullets.

El método UpdateScreen se encarga de actualizar la posición de todas las balas y refrescar la pantalla. También elimina el PictureBox de los controles del formulario y de la lista _bullets cuando llega a una posición determinada.